# Integral / Fourier Series

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Why is the following integral written with Fourier series development like this?

$\displaystyle h_i\sum_{k,l=1}^{\infty}a_k a_l \int_0^1 \sin(k\pi t)\sin(l\pi t) \,dt = \frac{h_i}{2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{\infty} a_k a_l \delta_{kl}$

What is used to move from left limb to right limb?

Thanks! :)

Comment: $\int_0^1\sin(k\pi t)\sin(l\pi t)dt=0$ if $l\neq t$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ if $l=t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply because, when $k\neq l$, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \sin (\pi  k t) \sin (\pi  l t) \, dt = \frac{l \sin (\pi  k) \cos (\pi  l)-k \cos (\pi  k) \sin (\pi  l)}{\pi  k^2-\pi  l^2} = 0
$$
And when $k=l$, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \sin (\pi  k t) \sin (\pi  k t) \, dt = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sin (2 \pi  k)}{4 \pi  k} = \dfrac{1}{2}
$$
Hence
$$
\int_0^1{\sin \left( k\pi t \right)}\sin \left( l\pi t \right) \,dt = \dfrac{1}{2} \delta_{kl}
$$
Thus your relation holds.